# From schema to SQL

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, cpanel, command-line-interface

I just started out with CakePHP and try to configure a plugin.

The plugin requires a table and contains a schema.php file that contains a class describing the table. From what I gather I have to run a command in my server CLI that will build a table according to this schema.

But my server doesn't seem to have  CLI (it's cPanel, and my website is hosted by a good but cheap host). I tried to access the server using Putty, but the connection is aborted when I try.

However, I do have phpMyAdmin where I can run SQL commands. So if I can 'convert' my schema.php in the appropiate SQL commands, I can copy these manually and run them. Is there an easy way to do this?

(I know, the fasted solution is probably to just enter the table by hand. but that would be boring)

Thank you!!

Scipio

Comment: If you try and run `schema.php` from a browser what happens?

Comment: CakePHP starts screaming ;)

Comment: The url is handled by CakePHP so the script is not executed in the end. If I place the file outside the Cake folder, I receive an error because it extends an existing CakePHP class

Comment: But that template class does contain the functions I need.. ;) getting there

Comment: You can import the schema locally, and dump the resultant table to an sql file.